# Bash - date: difference between %V and %W

Tags: date, gnu-coreutils

I want to get the week number using bash.

The man entry for `date` shows the following:

```
%V     ISO week number, with Monday as first day of week (01..53)
%W     week number of year, with Monday as first day of week (00..53)
```

Which is the difference?

This is the output I get:

```
$ date "+%W"
48
$ date "+%V"
48
```

Comment: Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the "correct" answer is, literally, given on Wikipedia when looking for "ISO week number"...

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit more clear in the GNU docs (referenced in the man page):

https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-conversion-specifiers.html#Date-conversion-specifiers

> ‘%W’ week number of year, with Monday as first day of week (‘00’…‘53’). Days in a new year preceding the first Monday are in week zero.
>
> ‘%V’ ISO week number, that is, the week number of year, with Monday as the first day of the week (‘01’…‘53’). If the week containing January 1 has four or more days in the new year, then it is considered week 1; otherwise, it is week 53 of the previous year, and the next week is week 1. (See the ISO 8601 standard.)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to depend on the year on this.  I like JoseKilo's explanation.

```
$ date +%V
32
$ date +%W
31
$ date
Mon Aug  5 08:29:23 MDT 2019
$

$ date -v-2y +%W
31
$ date -v-2y +%V
31
$ date -v-2y
Sat Aug  5 08:29:22 MDT 2017
$
```

Answer (score -1):

I would say there is a typo there:

```
 $ date "+%W"
52
 $ date "+%V"
52
 $ date
Sat Dec 30 10:42:06 CET 2017
```

Best regards

Comment: Date in your system is wrong. Think yourself, you are saying 52 weeks and it's still 1 month remaining. :p

Comment: Why add a speculative answer, when even minor research shows that's not the case?

Comment: @123 there you are right, I should have learn a bit more about calendars before answer :)